# Powershell get filename of killed process

Tags: powershell

I have a line of Powershell code that kills a process that has been running for more then 30 minutes (Excel). How can I also get the filename of the killed process?

```
Get-Process excel | 
    Where { $_.StartTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30) } | 
    Stop-Process -Force
```

Comment: Just ad a `select path` to get the full pathname of the process.

Comment: you want the path of the opened worksheet, right? so if you kill the Excel Process of `C:\excel\somefoosheet.xlsx` you want to get this path returned?

Answer (score 1):

<strike>This works for me but it might not be as you need it:</strike>

```
$filename = get-process excel | where-object { $_.StartTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1) } | select-object mainwindowtitle
write-host $filename 
get-process excel | where-object { $_.StartTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-1) } | stop-process -force
```

This outputs something on the line of: `@{MainWindowTitle=Microsoft Excel - testdata.xlsx]}`

You may want to append everything to a log so add something like `| out-file c:\testlog.txt` at the end of `$filename`.

Might be also good to get a timestamp.

**Edit: unfortunately this closes all excel files opened**

Edit2: I've experimented a bit thanks to Seth's comment and i got this to work:

```
Get-Process excel | Where-Object {$_.StartTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30)} | ForEach-Object {
    echo $_.Id, $_.MainWindowTitle;
    Stop-Process -Force -Id $_.id
}
```

It outputs to the window what it closes like this:

```
72148
Microsoft Excel - Book1
73712
Microsoft Excel - Book2
```

Comment: You could use a loop instead of a pipe and just do the `Select` and `Stop-Process` in the loop body. This way you'd only have do execute the `Get-Process` and `Where-Object` once and it would save you from possible edge cases like running the first line at 10:59:59 and running the third at 11:00:00.

Comment: I think this should work as intended now and edge cases should be avoided.

Comment: Nice, I submitted an edit for your code though. Your solution has an unnecessary second loop to output the `Id` and `MainWindowTitle` and you can actually use a pipe for it. You could've just extended your first solution by an additional pipe for `ForEach-Object`. It's just a minor improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below command,

```
c:\> powershell -command "get-Process | where-Object {$_.mainWindowTitle} | format-table id,name,mainwindowtitle -AutoSize"
```

This will list all of the processes that have a non-empty window title.

Store this list in some file using PS command,

Then,

Use code for killing running process such as,

```
Get-Process excel | Where { $_.StartTime -lt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-30) } | Stop-Process -Force
```

Then again list all of the processes that have a non-empty window title and compare with earlier list.

You will get process path of killed process and using string pattern evaluation you can get filename of the process.